# How to write a unit test without interface implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to unit testing.

I have to test `RefreshAmount` in the following code:

```
private readonly int id;

private readonly IService service;

public MyClass(int id, IService service)
{    
    this.id= id;
    this.service= service;    
}

public double Number { get; private set; }

public void RefreshAmount()
{    
    Number= service.GetTotalSum(id);    
}
```

What would be a correct unit test to write for `RefreshAmount`?

Comment: You are trying to unit test `RefreshAmount`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, yeah, that's right.

Comment: You're missing the `this` keyword in your constructor, with those parameter names.

Comment: @Merphy, thanks. It was just an example, that's why I missed it.

Comment: If what you meant was that you're trying to unit test `RefreshAmount`, [edit] your question to say so instead of just putting it in a comment, so that others besides @BradleyDotNET know that's what you're trying to do. Don't put valuable information in comments where it gets lost in the clutter - put it in the question itself.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for the suggestion. Edited. I didn't realize there's something else that I can test in this Class. I'm not sure on the best practices of unit testing. Do we also have to unit test constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **mock** `IService`. There are various frameworks that help automate this for you (like [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)) but here's a simple example:

```
public class MockService : IService
{
    public double GetTotalSum(int id)
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Basically, a mock implements your interface but just returns hard-coded (or otherwise well-known) data. That makes it easy to know what your expected value should be! Now you can use that to do your test:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    MyClass testObj = new MyClass(1, new MockService());

    testObj.RefreshAmount();
    Assert.Equals(10, testObj.Number);
}
```

Comment: MOC isn't needed here if op can construct an instance of service.  The real test is injecting proper integer values into the service object.  Which Mock would do if he had to do it.

Comment: @JohnPeters I respectfully disagree that a mock is not required. Testing each class *without* the dependencies helps ensure that they work when the dependencies are introduced (granted, I'd write both eventually). It also helps show you exactly where the problem is when you break something

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  Very good, thanks for your positive input.  I've been trying for about 15 years now to ensure developers are properly unit testing.  Most of them say "We just don't have the time to do it."  90% of all bugs are created during coding phases.  To me, Unit Tests should always come first because if the small parts are bullet proof Production pushes work really well.  Some professional test types say that Integration and System level tests are better than Unit Testing but I disagree with that.

Comment: @JohnPeters Yeah, good unit tests are important, its hard to find the time for them, but its worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Start simple attempting the "Sunny Day" or "Happy Path" first...

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
         var service = new MyService();
         int SomeProperInteger = GetNextInteger();
         double SomeProperAmount = .50;
         var actual = service.GetTotalSum(SomeProperInteger);
         double expected = SomeProperInteger * SomeProperAmount;
         Assert.IsTrue(expected = actual, "Test Failed, Expected amount was incorrect.");

    }
    private int GetNextInteger()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Start with testing a service object that will be used in production as shown above.  You will have to look at the code to see what GetTotalSum is supposed to do or look at the specifications. Once the "Happy path" works then you will alter at most 1 parameter at a time using Boundaries. The Boundaries would in code above come from GetNextInteger or a list of proper values.  You must write code to anticipate the expected value to compare.

After the service is validated to be working as designed, move on to the class that uses the service using the same techniques.

Comment: That would be an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: No it would be a good unit test.  If a developer cannot ensure their code is bullet proof they are pushing responsibility down the road.  Because all boundary conditions can be automated, it is a simple thing to test them.  I only recommend he test the service because he wouldn't need to mock it.  Most developers don't need to mock much because they have direct access to the code.

Comment: Agree with that, you absolutely need to test your boundary conditions.